# Rotate the user character on mouse position

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to get the character to rotate the character object based on where the mouse is.

So far I got it to rotate incrementally without mouse position. I was checking if it effected my zombie's chasing capabilities.

My script

```
let player, zombie, mouseX, mouseY;;

let bgCanvas = document.getElementById('backgroundCan');
function startGame() {
    document.getElementById("startScreen").style.display = "none";
    player = new playerComponent(350, 220);
    zombie = new zombieComponent(750, 220);
    gameArea.start();

}
```

```
let gameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 800;
        this.canvas.height = 500;
        this.canvas.style = "position: absolute";
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[2]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateArea, 20);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
          gameArea.keys = (gameArea.keys || []);
          gameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = true;
        })
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
          gameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = false;
        });
        this.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
          mouseX = e.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
          mouseY = e.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
        });
        this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
          let gShot = new Audio('assets/shot.mp3');
          gShot.play();
          var mX = e.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
          var mY = e.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
          if(mX >= zombie.x && mX < zombie.x+zombie.w && mY >= zombie.y && mY < zombie.y+zombie.h){
            if(zombie.health > 0){
              zombie.health += -1;
              zombie.speedX += 10;

              zombie.newPos();
              zombie.update();
            }
            else {
              zombie.status = "dead";
            }
          }
        });
    },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}
```

```
function playerComponent(x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;
    this.health = 10;
    this.status = "alive";
    let rotNum = 1;
    this.update = function(){
        ctx = gameArea.context;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
        ctx.rotate(rotNum * Math.PI / 180);
        playerSprite = new Image();
        playerSprite.src = "assets/playerGun.png";
        ctx.drawImage(playerSprite, 0, 0);
        ctx.restore();
        rotNum++;
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
      this.x += this.speedX;
      this.y += this.speedY;
    }

}
```

```
function updateArea() {
    gameArea.clear();
    if(player.status == "alive"){
      player.speedX = 0;
      player.speedY = 0;
      if (gameArea.keys && gameArea.keys[65]) {
        if(player.x > 20){
          player.speedX = -3;
        }
      }
      if (gameArea.keys && gameArea.keys[68]) {
        if(player.x < 740){
          player.speedX = 3;
        }
      }
      if (gameArea.keys && gameArea.keys[87]) {
        if(player.y > 20){
          player.speedY = -3;
        }
      }
      if (gameArea.keys && gameArea.keys[83]) {
        if(player.y < 445){
          player.speedY = 3;
        }
      }
      player.newPos();
      player.update();
    }
    if(zombie.status == "alive"){
      if(zombie.x > player.x){
        zombie.speedX = -1;
      }
      else{
        zombie.speedX = 1;
      }
      if(zombie.y > player.y){
        zombie.speedY = -1;
      }
      else{
        zombie.speedY = 1;
      }
      zombie.newPos();
      zombie.update();
    }
    else{
      zombie.update();
    }
}
```

So far, I have the mouse position on the canvas and am able to rotate the character, but I just don't how to connect the two. How should use the mouse position and the character position to rotate towards the mouse? The character is initially facing right (i think?), at least the sprite initially is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an image illustrating the situation:
[image]

You have the mouseY, playerY and mouseX, playerX

Therefore you can calculate the height and base of the triangle,
Thus the angle with [image: tan]
However, since in the second and third quadrants y/x will return an angle in the first and fourth quadrants, you need to use the Math.atan2(y,x) function in Javascript, not Math.atan(y/x). This will give you an angle between -180 and 180 instead of between -90 and 90.

Atan Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2

Then all you have to do is rotate based on the angle!

(P.S. Remember that you will have to convert between radians and degrees)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So angle should be something like this: Math.atan(mouseY-playerY/mouseX-playerX)? Which should return a radian I believe. Correct? Thanks again!

Comment: Math.atan((mouseY-playerY)/(mouseX-playerX)) <- remember the parentheses!
or
distY = mouseY-playerY
distX = mouseX-playerX
and then Math.atan(distY/distX)

Comment: It seems to be half working. Since the Math.atan() returns a radians it should be fine just inserting the value into the ctx.rotate() method right? But currently the character rotates properly half way then proceeds to be unable to rotate the full circle.

Comment: Thank you! It's working like a charm! Thank you for the help!

Comment: :) glad I could help